# I have a web part in my page and want to read some element from page that the web part is on

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, cross-domain, project-online

**I get this error: Protocols, domains, and ports must match**
Iframe has this domain and protocol: http:// www-ec65nhg76pg.mysite.com/
and Parent has this domain and protocol: http:// www.mysite.com/
I have used document.domain='mysite.com' in my web part but it didn't work.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it Visual Web Part or Content Editor? Can you please share the code snippet...

Comment: This is Visual Web Part.
parent.document.getElementById('#idCF_k33e2697-30cf-e511-80c6-00155d08bb1a');

Answer (score 0):

Is it a regular visual web part inside a WebPartZone? 
Usually you can access everything rendered in the page without navigating into parent/sibling/child stuff.

You are trying to do it with JS? The WebPart is in another domain and referenced with an Iframe?

Comment: They don't have the same origion. A web part  which has this domain :http:// www-ec65nhg76pg.mysite.com/ & its parent has another doamin: http:// www.mysite.com/ and web part wants to read an element which is outside the iframe(web part). Is it possible to do?

Comment: That is usually followed by this kind of "cross domain policy" issue. I honestly don't think this can be avoided, because it is probably related to a HTTP/Browser/Security limitation.